# How to make CLion use different CMake config for debug and release?

Tags: cmake, clion

I built 2 separate debug and release versions of OpenCV. How can I switch between 2 builds when I debug my project? I tried this:

```
IF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES DEBUG)
    message(WARNING "debug mode")
    find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED
            PATHS /path/to/debug/build NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
ELSE()
    message(WARNING "release mode")
    find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
ENDIF()
```

but it doesn't work. It does show `release mode` when I build normally, but doesn't show `debug mode` or `release mode` when the debugger kicks in. My thought is that `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` will be set to `Debug` when I debug. Is that true?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the value of `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE `?

Comment: @KamilCuk it's `Debug`. Somehow the messages printed to stderr when I ran but it doesn't print now. I edit the answer a lil bit too.

Comment: So it's "Debug" not DEBUG. So compare it with Debug `if (${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Debug")`.

Comment: Yes I've just found that. Seems I need another question, due to the fact that CLion will just set it to `Debug` if not specified in its config files, and somehow CLion doesn't load the `Debug` build of OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

`MATCHES` in cmake `if` is case sensitive. So when comparing `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` you have to decide on case. It's popular to convert to string into upper case and do comparisons then:

```
string(TOUPPER ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_UP)
if (${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_UP} STREQUAL "DEBUG")
   ...
```

Or the best is to compare against the standard values defiuned in [cmake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.htm): `Possible values are empty, Debug, Release, RelWithDebInfo and MinSizeRel`. Note that both `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=dEbUg` and `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DeBuG` both will configure for Debug build, but the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable will differ. So the safest way is to convert it to upper case.

Comment: "Note that cmake ignores the case on input..." - Not quite true. CMake just uses `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` variable for both `dEbUg` and `DeBuG` builds, but case of input is never ignored. The only case is ignored by CMake is a case of **commands names**: `string` and `STRING` are treated equally. I would delete the phrase about "ignore case on input" for do not confuse the readers. The remaining of the sentence more correctly reflects the situation: "`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=dEbUg` and `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DeBuG` both will configure for Debug build".